# Script inserts the same values to the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

When I run this code, I get some fields updated to my MySQL table but for some reason it is all the same value.

```
$query = $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('sender')->get($sender_table);
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data = array(
            $sender_row => $row->$sender_row
    );
    $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver')->update($receiver_table, $data);
}
```

[image]

print_r($data) returns:

> Array (
>       [Strasse] => Pantherstr. ) Array (
>       [Strasse] => Minimalweg ) Array (
>       [Strasse] => Blankeneser Weg )

How can I fix this?

Comment: the result is expected.do you have any id column or unique column?

Comment: You need to define `where` condition also to identify which row must updated on which condition..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a $ to many in $row->sender_row:

```
$query = $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('sender')->get($sender_table);
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data = array(
            $sender_row => $row->sender_row
    );
    $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver')->update($receiver_table, $data);
}
```

Comment: No, `$row->$sender_row` should be correct. $sender_row is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you will find is happening is that in all of your Rows, the Strasse fields will be getting set to 
Pantherstr, then to Minimalweg then to Blankeneser Weg.

So what you are seeing is the Final Value that is being written to ALL Rows.

I do not see where your Where is. If you want to update a particular row or rows, you need to identify those rows. Else ALL rows will be getting updated each time through your loop.

Comment: Is there a way to add these fields to the column without using Where to identify them? They should only be listed from up to down, no matter what.

Comment: When you update column(s) in any table and do not specify any WHERE conditions to identify the row or rows you wish to update , then ALL rows will be updated.

Comment: I thought it could be possible to run a loop to say the first row gets the first value, the second row gets the second value and so on...

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? It looks like you have two different Databases... one with a Senders Table and the other with a Receivers table! A Sender can send to many Receivers, as your own data shows - you have only 3 entries from your Senders Table and 6 in your Receivers table... So Which Receiver gets which Senders Address (Strasse)? More importantly, WHY set a receivers address to a senders address? The fact that you are attempting to do this means that you need some relationship between the sender and the receiver!